# What is this statement => ($value ? $value : 0)

Tags: php

I don't get this operation. Is that a quick if/else statement ?

Inside a HTML :
`<?= $LU ? $LU : 0 ?>`

Directly in PHP :
`$LU ? $LU : 0`

I have no idea what it does

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: It's called a "ternary operator" and yes, it's a short form of `if-else`.

Answer (score 0):

This is called **Ternary Operator**, you can refer to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

> The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1
> evaluates to true, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to false.